"background-attachment: fixed" Parallax Effect in Safari jumpy & choppy
I have a very simple parallax effect on my website. It simply uses "background-attachment: fixed" to achieve this (so not true parallax).
I've been searching and trying different solutions for days and can't find a fix other than to forego the parallax effect on Safari by removing this styling if its detected.
Please, if anyone has a solution to such a simple problem, it would be greatly appreciated.
I've found that Safari's animations are actually SO much smoother than on Chrome but the fact that you can't have this basic effect is disheartening.
Full CSS for the parallax element:
height: 518px;
background-image: url(..img);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-size: 100%;
background-color: transparent;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;

Tried the solutions on this thread except jQuery plugin: My fixed background made scrolling the site very slow, what can I do to improve it?
